# How to edit biography using php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to allow users to edit their biography and on the page I want the editable text from the DB to appear in the text box. How do I do this? Currently I have the text as a placeholder, but I want to make that editable.

Also for other, shorter fields like a users company name, when I insert the value as the placeholder (I don't want it to be editable like the bio so it doesn't resubmit every time), it can't display more than one word. How can I fix this.

Note: I wrote a function that only displays a value from SQL if there is one, else it displays a generic text, i.e. "bio" or "email"

Here is my function where $content is something like $_POST["bio"] and

```
<?php
function echo_content($content,$name)
{
if(!empty($content)){
    echo($content);
}
else{
    echo($name);
}
}
?>
```

Below is my html/php where $content is a value from SQL.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <legend>Bio: </legend><textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" name="bio" 
placeholder=<?php echo_content($content[0]["bio"],"Bio");?> type="text"/></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: Echo it in the `textarea` rather than placeholder.. `<?php echo_content($content[0]["bio"],"Bio");?>` move before `</textarea>` and change `type="text"/>` to `>`. There is not `type` on a textarea because it is a text area. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 0):

You're dumping a string into an html attribute, WITHOUT quotes, so basically you're producing:

```
<textarea ... placeholder=Four Score and Seven Years ago type="text">
```

so your placeholder is `Four`, and then there's a bunch of unknown/illegal attributes, `Score`, `and`, `Seven` etc...

Try

```
<textarea ... placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var) ?>" ...>
```

instead. note the `"` and use of htmlspecialchars() to quote out html metachars.

In other words, you're basically suffering from a self-inflicted HTML injection wound.

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick and great response! You are a fire breathing dragon!

Comment: `Placeholder` content isn't editable though, or is it?

Comment: placeholder is basically "click here to edit" until something REALLY gets filled in. `<textarea>$var</textarea>` would be the proper way of presenting "old" content for editing.